# UICFFont autoreleased with no pool in place?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uifont

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(3165, 1197, 332,43);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
myLabel.text = @"WASHINGTON D. C.";
```

> NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object
>   0x7a39750 of class UICFFont
>   autoreleased with no pool in place -
>   just leaking NSAutoreleaseNoPool():
>   Object 0x6fc3920 of class
>   UITextRenderingAttributes autoreleased
>   with no pool in place - just leaking

the stack trace from a breakpoint in the above code can be found here : [img52.imageshack.us/img52/9616/tutc.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/9616/tutc.png)

I'm using iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller (it includes Tiling View.h)

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: thank you, i'll test all questions and accept most suitable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this code being run on a background thread?

You need to make an autorelease pool

```
// At the start of your thread
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

...
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(3165, 1197, 332,43);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
myLabel.text = @"WASHINGTON D. C.";
...

// At the very end of your thread
[pool release];
```

Comment: Is this code being run on a background thread? may be, but i'm not sure. I need time to test it? /*At the start of your thread*/ Can i paste this code in the middle of background thread?

Comment: To test it just put a breakpoint on that line. Then, when the debugger stops there it will tell you which thread it's on.

Comment: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect - call my function that create myLabel

Comment: I paste these 2 lines of code (autorelease pool) , but it did not help me. The problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Oh. Can you add more code to your question please - the call stack from your reakpoint would be useful as well.

Comment: OK so you're definitely in a background thread (Thread 3) - what are you trying to put a UILabel on?

Comment: [self addSubview:myLabel];, where @interface TilingView : UIView

Comment: but what's causing the tiling view to be drawn on a seperate thread - drawInRect is usually only called on the main thread

Comment: I use iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller (it includes Tiling View.h), i can attach code if it is necessary

Comment: Oh. I've not used that - I'll take a look into it but can't really help you much more. I think that the problem is that you're drawing on a background thread but I might be wrong because I don't know the code you're using. Sorry!